# creating a column in dataframe pandas based on a condition

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists

```
A = ['a','b','c','d','e']
B = ['c','e']
```

A dataframe with column

```
      A
  0   a
  1   b
  2   c
  3   d
  4   e
```

I wish to create an additional column for rows where elements in B matches A.

```
      A  M
  0   a
  1   b
  2   c match
  3   d
  4   e match
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df.loc[df.A.isin(B), 'M'] = 'match'
print (df)
   A      M
0  a    NaN
1  b    NaN
2  c  match
3  d    NaN
4  e  match
```

Or:

```
df['M'] = np.where(df.A.isin(B),'match','')
print (df)

   A      M
0  a       
1  b       
2  c  match
3  d       
4  e  match
```